# Реализация бота для угадывания числа

Tags: javascript

Стояла следующая задача:

> Написать простой игровой бот, который умеет следующее:
>
> предлагает пользователю ввести свой вариант отгадки;
>
> если пользовательское число больше, чем загаданное, то бот выводит
>   “Меньше!” и предлагает ввести новый вариант;
>
> если пользовательское число меньше, чем загаданное, то бот выводит
>   “Больше!” и предлагает ввести новый вариант;
>
> если пользователь вводит правильное число, то бот выводит
>   “Правильно!”;
>
> если пользователь ввел не число, то выводит “Введи число!”;
>
> если пользователь нажимает “Отмена”, то игра заканчивается.
>
> Подсказка: пригодятся стандартные JS-функции: prompt, alert,
>   Math.random и parseInt.

Я реализовал вот так:

```js
min = Math.ceil(1);
max = Math.floor(50);

var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
console.log(number);

function start() {

  while (true) {

    let userNumber = prompt('Enter the number');
    console.log(typeof(parseInt(userNumber)));

    if (isNaN(userNumber)) {
      alert('Enter please number');
      continue;
    }

    if (userNumber === null) {
      alert('Bye bye :)');
      break;
    }

    if (parseInt(userNumber) === number) {
      alert('You win');
      break;
    } else if (parseInt(userNumber) > number) {
      alert('Your number more');
    } else if (parseInt(userNumber) < number) {
      alert('Your number less');
    }
  }
}

start();
```

Вопрос: можно ли было это реализовать как-то проще? Без `break` и `continue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Саму логику проверок особо не укоротить, потому что всё равно нужно рассмотреть все варианты
- Вместо `continue` можно использовать `else`, но это принципиально ничего не меняет
- "`while (true)` + `break`" лично я очень не люблю, но использование вместо этого "`while` + флаг" опять-таки меняет что-то лишь на уровне субъективного восприятия

---

Так как логика рассмотрения всех вариантов схожа (проверка + текст + "продолжать/не продолжать"), то их можно описать в одном стиле заранее, а в цикле проверять их по очереди. Решение при этом проще не выглядит - просто немного другой подход:

```js
min = Math.ceil(1);
max = Math.floor(50);
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
console.log(number);

const handlers = [
  { check: value => value === null, toContinue: false, text: "Bye bye :)" },
  { check: value => isNaN(parseInt(value)), toContinue: true, text: "Enter please number" },
  { check: value => parseInt(value) === number, toContinue: false, text: "You win" },
  { check: value => parseInt(value) > number, toContinue: true, text: "Your number more" },
  { check: value => parseInt(value) < number, toContinue: true, text: "Your number less" }
];

let isGuessing = true;
while (isGuessing) {
  const value = prompt("Enter the number");
  const matchedHandler = handlers.find(handler => handler.check(value));
  isGuessing = matchedHandler.toContinue;
  alert(matchedHandler.text);
}
```

Условие `isNaN(value)` заменил на `isNaN(parseInt(value))`, чтобы пустые строки, а также строки, состоящие из пробелов, тоже как-то обрабатывались: [isNaN на них возвращает false](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)